# iOS 13: Emoji keyboard size is wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm animating my constraints when keyboard appears.
I'm using this code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

and

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let current = view.getSelectedTextField()
        
        // is it not visible?
        if(current != nil)
        {
            let frame = self.view.convert(current!.frame, from: current!.superview)
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                let space = CGFloat(16.0)
                let diff = ((self.view.frame.height - keyboardSize.height - space) - (frame.origin.y + frame.height))
                if(diff < 0)
                {
                    self.view.frame.origin.y = diff
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

which works perfectly for normal character keyboards, but for emoji keyboard it's height is completely wrong.

Is emoji keyboard size calculated in some other way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification responder

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

The above method gets called each time frame of keyboard gets changed. You get the new frame and write your code accordingly.

Comment: This worked great!  So I simply reset my view size to be as if it had no keyboard whenever keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification is called, trusting that keyboardDidShowNotification will then be called with the size of the different keyboard it's switching to (emoji or dictation).  Works great. Thanks!